# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 while running play framework

Tags: playframework

I know there is version conflict. Just want someone to tell me how to resolve it. In previous stackoverflow post no one tells the solution.

Versions:
Ubuntu: 12.04.1 LTS
java: 1.6.0_24 (OpenJDK)
javac: 1.7.0_07 (OpenJDK)

```
haider@haider-desktop:~/Documents/projects/java-projects/mytestapp$ play
[info] Loading project definition from /home/haider/Documents/projects/java-projects/mytestapp/project
[info] Set current project to mytestapp (in build file:/home/haider/Documents/projects/java-projects/mytestapp/)
       _            _ 
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/ 

play! 2.0.4, http://www.playframework.org

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[mytestapp] $ run

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000...

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$javascript : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$ref : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$javascript : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$ref : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$javascript : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$ref : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/app/controllers/Application.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/Application$Hello : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/app/controllers/Application.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/Application : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/app/controllers/Application.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/Application$Hello : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/haider/Documents/projects/libraries/play-2.0.4/samples/java/helloworld/app/controllers/Application.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/Application : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/Application$Hello : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/Application : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are using different JDK versions to compile and run the application. You say that:

```
java: 1.6.0_24 (OpenJDK) 
javac: 1.7.0_07 (OpenJDK)
```

So your compiler (javac) is a newer release than the *java* command, which means the second can't run your compiled files. You must use only 1 version of the JDK (same for java and javac)

Comment: I didn't know that it is going to be that easy. I uninstalled openjdk-7 and then installed openjdk-6.. And now it is working!!!!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 23):

On Ubuntu to change Java version for both compiling and running you need to call:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

and

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 5):

A better solution is to change the target version, so you could compile to 1.6 from 1.7 like this:
[How can I set the javac compile version for Play Framework 2.0 to prevent "Unsupported major.minor version"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807724/how-can-i-set-the-javac-compile-version-for-play-framework-2-0-to-prevent-unsup)

Put this in your Build.scala:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  // Force compilation in java 1.6
  javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6")
)
```

Comment: I had the same problem with spark-notebook (https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook) and this advice fixed the problem.

Comment: Couldn't find this file anywhere, when I put the code in build.sbt got errors