# How can I set the javac compile version for Play Framework 2.0 to prevent "Unsupported major.minor version"?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

A module I am using must have been compiled with Java 1.7, and I only have 1.6.

If I want to for the module to be compiled for a specific version like 1.6, how can I set that in Play! Framework 2.0 so that I can prevent the "Unsupported major.minor version" errors.

In Play! 1.x you could set "java.version=1.6" in the application.conf.

I assume that in Play! 2.x it probably needs to be set somewhere for sbt - but where/how?

Answer (score 19):

Adding

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6")
```

to the **build.sbt** file worked for me (to be transparent, in my case it was 1.7 to build with JDK 8).

Comment: I think 1.7 means building with JDK 7, and 1.8 with JDK 8. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 8):

In the file **project/Build.scala**, add the setting below if you want to compile with java 1.6 :

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  // Force compilation in java 1.6
  javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6")
)
```

Comment: this looks promising, Thanks!

Comment: and here it is on to find on my [blog](http://www.poornerd.com/2013/07/25/how-to-set-the-java-version-for-compiling-a-play-framework-module/)

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, put

```
javaHome := Some(file("path_to_your_jdk"))
```

at the very end of your build.sbt file. Make sure your put it after "*playJavaSettings*" (if you have this line in your built.sbt).

Make sure you have the right path assigned to your sdk , you can verify this by typing :

```
java-home
```

in Play or activator console.

Also make sure you run

```
clean
```

in your console to get rid of all previously compiled resources.

now compile your code using

```
compile
```

you should be good to go. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to create the file **build.sbt** in the root of the project and add

> javaHome := Some(file("path_to_your_jdk"))

Comment: I just want to set the version like in ant java target="1.5"