# How to specify jdk 1.7 compliance level when using 1.8 in play framework 2.2.2

Tags: java, playframework

I am using jdk 1.8 for development in java using play framework. However I need to build for 1.7 target. I already tried using

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")
```

in build.sbt as given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807724/how-can-i-set-the-javac-compile-version-for-play-framework-2-0-to-prevent-unsup) answer.

Comment: In what way is specifying the target version using compiler flags not working?

Comment: I don't think it is working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143684/can-java-8-code-be-compiled-to-run-on-java-7-jvm.

Comment: @Kris No it should work. In the link you provide, the author tries to compile Java 8 code to comply with Java 7 (i.e, source 1.8, target 1.7), which cannot work. In the current question, the OP is compiling Java 7 code to comply with Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I think I got it figured out. Strange behavior - its working after I moved the javacOptions line to the beginning. Previously it was in the end! This is the working build.sbt settings now.

```
name := "TestService"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.8.Final"
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```