# Play Framework InjectedRoutesGenerator Error

Tags: scala, playframework

I have created new Play + Scala project using latest typesafe activator and when trying to import in IntelliJ IDE I was getting below error,

> info] Loading project definition from E:\Personal\Scala Workspace\DeployZip\project
>   E:\Personal\Scala Workspace\DeployZip\build.sbt:18: error: not found: value routesGenerator
>   routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
>   ^
>   [error] Type error in expression
>   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

What are the possible reasons for this error?

Comment: I suggest sharing your `build.sbt` and `project/plugins.sbt` content then that should help. A guess would be that the Play plugin isn't ready by that point. (Is there `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")` in `project/plugins.sbt`?)

Comment: @bjfletcher I have added plugin and build sbt files along with my java and scala version.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed jdk 1.8 and now I am able to create project successfully without any error.

But when I tried to run play application using

> activator run

I was getting below error now,

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/webjars/WebJarExtractor$Cache : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Comment: Need to ensure the same Java version for both compiling and running, some advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722381/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-while-runing-play-framework

Comment: @bjfletcher Thanks for the link. I have checked it at my side and both java and javac version is same and it is 1.8.0_45-b15. Still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Try deleting the target folders or `sbt clean` in case there's some old stuff lying about

Comment: @bjfletcher even I got the same error when try to run **sbt clean** from my project. And my **sbt clean** command end up with,  `[error] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/webjars/WebJarExtractor$Cach
e : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? `

Comment: I have the same problem, have you figured out it?

Comment: No I have not yet figure it out. I tried all options I found.

Comment: Same problem for me and no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~simpkins/teaching/gatech/cs2340/guides/java7-macosx.html), I think `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` means that your play application were compiled with **Java 1.7 (version 51)**, but you have **Java 1.8 (version 52)** installed instead, so you got this error. I'd suggest that you refer to [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/650310/switching-between-java-7-and-8-in-os-x) for how you could switch between different Java versions.

I was having the error that said `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`, and after I installed the latest one (Java 1.8) it was solved.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done to solve the issue. Even if you install the java 1.8 it is not sufficient. You have to update the 'path' and 'JAVA_HOME'.

After you install, try to set the jdk1.8 path in the PATH of the environment variables. Also make sure that if you have other versions of the java in the PATH then put the jdk 1.8 path prior to the previous version of java. Or just in case put it in the very beginning of the paths.

Comment: I have tried even after setting up 'JAVA_HOME' to 1.8 but still not luck and having same issue.

Comment: @Nishan did you restart the command line window?(I know you may have done, just want to make sure)

Comment: yes I tried it. Even I have tried to delete .ivy and other folders, also intalles jdk 1.8, Scala, SBT again but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Everything worked after I upgraded Intellij to the latest version (maybe my outdated version used JDK1.7, while activator used 1.8?).